# What does a hashtag subscript mean?

Tags: measure-theory, notation, geometric-measure-theory

I've been coming accross notation like this $\gamma = (id,id)_\# \mu$, where the hashtag/pound sign is used in the subscript. From context, it seems to have something to do with marginalizing probability measures, but I can't seem to find any resource that defines this notation.

For an example of the usage, you can see page 2 of [these lecture notes](https://lchizat.github.io/files2020ot/lecture3.pdf) by Chizat.

Comment: Possibly a push forward / pull back measure notation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [@FShrike'scomment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4439336/what-does-a-hashtag-subscript-mean#comment9293968_4439336), I was able to confirm that this indicates a push-forward measure.  If anyone in the future is looking for a definition to reference, I found it in Exercise 1.4.38 (p.103) of Terence Tao's "[An Introduction to Measure Theory](https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/gsm-126-tao5-measure-book.pdf)":
$$
\phi_\# \mu(E) = \mu(\phi^{-1}(E)).
$$